# Is it possible to have Persistent Bottom Sheet as a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

I want to make Persistent Bottom Sheet as a Fragment inside a Fragment but can't find anywhere how to achieve it. Everywhere Persistent Bottom Sheet is added as a layout inside activity/fragment but is it possible to make Persistent Bottom Sheet as a Fragment so that I can reuse that view some where else?

Comment: Show us the code to see if we can help you somehow

Comment: Wondering if you already have a working code for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing tutorial on `BottomSheet` in [AndroidHive](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/)

You can create a class extending `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    public BottomSheetFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog, container, 
              false);
    }
}
```

And toggle it using below code

```
BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
```

Comment: I don't need Modal Bottom sheet. I want Persistent Bottom sheet.

Comment: Sounds like creating a Generic `BottomSheetBehavior` class is what you need.

Comment: if you dont want  a modal bottomsheet then dont extend BottomSheetDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `FragmentContainerView` inside the layout that will be used as persistent bottom sheet, then add the Fragment you want to reuse that `FragmentContainerView`

Answer (score -3):

You can use BottomSheetDialogFragment,I imagine you want to do just like this: [image: Modal Bottom Sheet Image]

Then create the navigationView file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/state_pressed"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And create file menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/round_home_24"
            android:title="Inicio"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_settings_24"
            android:title="Configuración"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/round_mail_outline_24"
            android:title="Email"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_search_24"
            android:title="Buscar" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/outline_lock_24"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/outline_account_circle_24"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

And create the file for borderRadius

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="90dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="90dp" />
            <padding android:left="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

And create state_pressed backgroud color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/border_radius_tabs">
        <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></color>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
<color android:color="@color/primaryLightColor"></color>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: This seems like a good alternative to me, but can you provide some code as to how to use it? And maybe some ideas as of how you plan to make it reusable?